# how p-paginator works

Tags: primeng, paginator

by setting [rows]='10' and [paginator] = 'true' I can get what I want. But now I want to control p-datatable by using p-paginator in order to use onPageChange() to get the pageNumber. So how can I associate these two tags.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nexi0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
...    
[paginator]="true" 
[rows]="10" 
[rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,50]"  
[totalRecords]="dataset?.length"
(onPage)="fn($event)"
...
```

In this way you can calculate actual page.

```
fn(event:any){
   let pageNumber = Math.ceil(event.first/event.rows);
}
```

Comment: I need to control p-datatable by using p-paginator.
by the way (onPage) function can only get first and row but can`t get the page number i want